# Nexus: Configure jarvana as a remote repository -- what's the URL?

Tags: maven-2, nexus

I'm converting an Ant build system to use a local Nexus mirror (1.3.6), and can't seem to get Nexus to proxy Jarvana repository.  One of our dependencies is jython 2.5, which is available only on Jarvana.

I had no problem configuring other repository proxies, such as java.net at http://download.java.net/maven/2/

For Jarvana I've tried

```
www.jarvana.com/
www.jarvana.com/jarvana/
www.jarvana.com/maven2/
www.jarvana.com/maven/2/
www.jarvana.com/browse/
```

In all cases, the browse pane shows .index and .meta folders, and the .index is populated with nexus-maven-repository-index-* files, but searching for jython returns only the earlier (2.2 and prior) versions from Maven Central.

Am I using the wrong URL, and if so what URL should I be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I did a bit more digging and it looks like the repository URL for Jarvana is http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/browse. I've just added Jarvana as a proxy repository with that URL and successfully downloaded Jython 2.5.

Comment: I just tried this.  My Nexus seems to accept it, and the .index and .meta directories are populated, but it still doesn't find jython.  What version of Nexus are you using?

Comment: I'm on 1.3.6. Have you added the jarvana repository to your settings and/or your Nexus group?

Comment: It seems to have taken a while, but the URL you gave me is now working.  See also @DeronEriksson's answer and my comments.

Comment: Accepting this since it answers my original question.  Thanks also to Deron Eriksson.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using the jarvana url as it just copies central and it's possible (I haven't checked) that it's sending redirects to central which would just slow your system down.

Answer (score 4):

Jarvana offers [maven repository search](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/) capabilities and maven repository browse capabilities, but it does not offer a direct URL for its repository files. This is because all Jarvana files come from the maven central repository, so every file in Jarvana should be available in the maven central repository.

As an example, Jython 2.5 is available in the central repository at:
repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/python/jython/2.5.0/

Comment: Curiously, I don't see 2.5.0 in Maven Central in NEXUS, only 2.2.1. However, the URL you provided seems to point to 2.5, so there may be a problem in Nexus indexing.  I tried expiring the cache and reindexing, with no effect.

Comment: I looked at <code>/maven2/org/python/jython/maven-metadata.xml</code> and see that it lists only 2.2.1, so that must be the problem.